# System.MissingMethodException from a class that has property of type byref<_>

Tags: f#

I'm having difficulties using [RBush](https://github.com/viceroypenguin/RBush) from F#. The library requires me to define a class that implements the following interface.

```
public interface ISpatialData
{
    ref readonly Envelope Envelope { get; }
}
```

Below is the code of a console application that compiles fine, where `Point` class implements the `ISpatialData` interface.

```
open RBush

type Point(minX, minY, maxX, maxY) =
    let mutable envelope = Envelope(minX, minY, maxX, maxY)
    interface ISpatialData with
        member __.Envelope = &envelope

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
    let tree = RBush<Point>()
    0
```

However, when the application is run it throws: `System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'RBush.Envelope ByRef RBush.ISpatialData.get_Envelope()'.'`

If I send the `Point` class definition to F# Interactive I get the following error: `error FS0193: internal error: Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match.  Type: 'Point'.  Assembly: 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This usually indication of you using different FSharp.Core than used for the library. Modify app.config to have following:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=_Your .Net Version_" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-_Your FSharp.Core Version_" newVersion="_Your FSharp.Core Version_" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem. Since RBush is implemented in C# it does not depend on FSharp.Core thus I don't think this is related to using wrong FSharp.Core version. However, thanks for trying to solve my problem.